# React: How can I apply CSS transition effects when an element is rendered?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a checkbox that, when checked, exposes part of a form, eg:

```
                        <label>
                            <input
                                name="postalAddressNeeded"
                                type="checkbox"
                                value={this.state.postalAddressNeeded}
                                onChange={this.handlePostalCheckChange}
                            />
                            My postal address is different my residential address
                        </label>

                        {postalAddressNeeded &&
                            <div>
                                <AddressAutocomplete />
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    }
```

This works, but I'd like to animate it to slide down when the checkbox is checked. To that affect I have created:

```
{postalAddressNeeded &&
  <div className={`js-inactive ${postalAddressNeeded ? 'js-slide-down-show' : 'js-slide-down-hide'}`}>
   <AddressAutocomplete />
  </div>
}
```

and in my CSS:

```
.js-inactive {
    height: 0px;
}

.js-slide-down-show {
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease;
}

.js-slide-down-hide {
    height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease;
}
```

However this does not work - the element still appears but there are no animations.

I've investigated other ways of doing this IE with the `react-transition-group` plugin, but it looks like that does work with rendering elements.

Would anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: You cant do css transitions with 'auto'.  You have to define the height. There are different tricks you can do to get around it depending on your implementation.  I would search for that

Comment: I think `postalAddressNeeded  && ` is not needed if you're already controlling it conditionally in the class. Also as @coot3 pointed out about auto height

Answer (score 1):

Here is [small sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-worker-7dbko3?file=/src/App.js), with some explanations in the styles.

In the comments, `coot3` and `Servesh Chaturvedi` are both right, just combine their answers.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that mean the field is still rendered but just hidden in CSS? What if I want that field to be required?

Comment: That's right, its hidden. Validation can be configured according to condition, for example: field is required if there is data in another field. Otherwise, you need to use third party solutions.